# A difference between startof and firstof values of indexAt parameter in to.period

Tags: r, xts

According to the documentation:

> To adjust the final indexing style, it is possible to set indexAt to
>   one of the following: ‘yearmon’, ‘yearqtr’, ‘firstof’, ‘lastof’,
>   ‘startof’, or ‘endof’. The final index will then be yearmon, yearqtr,
>   the first time of the period, the last time of the period, the
>   starting time in the data for that period, or the ending time in the
>   data for that period, respectively.

Now I try to do `to.hourly` for my minute data. I see that all values by default is set to the last minute in data. I want to set to the first minute. It seems `indexAt` is parameter exactly for that. I have one hour that starts at 09:30. As I understand from description `'firstof'` should set it to 09:00 (first minute of hourly period) and `'startof'` should set it to 09:30 (first available minute in hour data). `'startof'` seems to work for me but `'firstof'` does not work and still returns 09:59! Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the *Usage* section of `?to.period`, you will see that only `to.monthly` and `to.quarterly` have `indexAt` arguments. That is why `to.hourly` ignores the `indexAt` argument.

[Issue #158](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/xts/issues/158) briefly discusses the possibility of adding `indexAt` support for periods other than monthly and quarterly.

Comment: OK thanks for info. I agree with you that this is a bit inconsistent. On top of that 'startof' seems to work for some reason (probably because it is same logic for all timeframes - just take first existing element in period).